# Theming node for views page

Tags: views

I created a new views page which lists specific content types(products). And i have specific node node--products.tpl template file which is being used in views. I want to be able to use specific node template for views. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Other section of the views edit form, there is a link "Theme: Information." Inside that link there is a list of the many ways to template the view output. As always when theming, you start by copying the base file (e.g., views-view-unformatted.tpl.php), and make your modifications to the copy. Follow the naming conventions given in the link exactly. It can sometimes be tricky to get the dashes correct. Double-dashes are used to separate sections within the filename but single dashes are used to replace single underscores in content names. For example, for a content type named article_ratings, the template file would be named views-view-unformatted--article-ratings--default.tpl.php.